Problem with downgrading React JS from 18 to 17 version
I have problem with downgrading React Js from 18 to 17 version. My server is Ubuntu 22.04 with HestiaCP panel.
Command npm view react version outputs:
18.3.1
I try npm uninstall react to uninstall current version and then install needed version, but after executing this command I still get:
18.3.1
How could I resolve my problem and install 17 version instead 18?
Uninstall current version.

install needed version What command are you doing to install it?

@NicholasTower npm install react@17.0.0 but npm view react version still outputs 18.3.1

K, that install command looks right. And if you check your package.json file, what version does it say? I think it's installing what you want it to, it's just that npm view react version is not the right command to tell you what you have installed. That command tells you what the latest version is on npm.
